# Neo4j not using indices

Tags: neo4j

Currently I am trying this query on Neo4j 2.2.2

At the time of this post, we have not labeled any nodes yet as we recently upgraded from Neo4j 1.x.   so we don't have the option of making use of the USING clause.

I am trying to uses indices but ending up with full table scans.

```
START pfComp=node:Company('id:2403226') , ptComp=node:Company('id:1946633')
OPTIONAL MATCH
     (pfComp)<-[c:CHILD_OF*]-(cfComp)
WITH collect(id(cfComp)) as cfCompIds, ptComp, pfComp
OPTIONAL MATCH
                (ptComp)<-[c2:CHILD_OF*]-(ctComp)
WITH  cfCompIds, collect(id(ctComp)) AS ctCompIds
MATCH
                (fComp) -[fR:PARTICIPATES_IN]->  cdeals <-[tR:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(tComp)
WHERE
                (fComp.id = 2403226 or id(fComp) in  cfCompIds) and
                (tComp.id = 1946633 or id(tComp) in ctCompIds)
RETURN fComp, tComp, cdeals
```

Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 1305292 total db hits in 79128 ms.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Below is the full profile command output.

[image: This is the explain plan for the query]

The beginning portion of the query performs fast:

```
profile START pfComp=node:Company('id:2403226') , ptComp=node:Company('id:1946633')
OPTIONAL MATCH
     (pfComp)<-[c:CHILD_OF*]-(cfComp)
WITH collect(id(cfComp)) as cfCompIds, ptComp, pfComp
OPTIONAL MATCH
                (ptComp)<-[c2:CHILD_OF*]-(ctComp)
return   cfCompIds, collect(id(ctComp)) AS ctCompIds
```

Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 836 total db hits in 582 ms.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have an typo here? You use identifiers you have not initialized before, so it has to do a very very bad full scane and expand: `OPTIONAL MATCH (ptComp)<-[c2:CHILD_OF*]-(ctComp)`

Comment: these here have inconsistent ways of defining their lookup, for the property  lookup you miss the label and the id() lookup conflicts with the prop lookup  I'd split it up into two parts of a union

Comment: Michael Hunger:  The begging portion of the query is fine:  
  
profile START pfComp=node:Company('id:2403226') ,   ptComp=node:Company('id:1946633')  
OPTIONAL MATCH  
     (pfComp)<-[c:CHILD_OF*]-(cfComp)  
WITH collect(id(cfComp)) as cfCompIds, ptComp, pfComp  
OPTIONAL MATCH  
                (ptComp)<-[c2:CHILD_OF*]-(ctComp)  
return   cfCompIds, collect(id(ctComp)) AS ctCompIds    
Result:  
Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 836 total db hits in 582 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second part looks like a relational join, or an additional lookup (like an n+1 select).
Perhaps use the graph model instead? And the query gets simpler too.

So you would compute `fComp` and `tComp` with the initial matches, due to the `*0..` it includes pfComp and ptComp each.

Then you have the cross over between fComp and tComp for the last match.

Please try it out and see how it fares:

```
MATCH (pfComp:lCompany)<-[c:CHILD_OF*0..]-(fComp:lCompany)
WHERE pfComp.id = 2403226
// reduce cardinality for following match
WITH collect(distinct fComp) as companies1
MATCH (ptComp:lCompany)<-[c2:CHILD_OF*]-(tComp:lCompany)
WHERE ptComp.id = 1946633
// create cross product between fComp and tComp
UNWIND companies1 as fComp
MATCH (fComp) -[fR:PARTICIPATES_IN]->(cdeals)<-[tR:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(tComp)
RETURN  fComp, tComp, cdeals;
```

Comment: Wasn't expecting to get much better performance for this, but you increased the performance 3 fold.   Thank you good sir.  Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 40525 total db hits in 307 ms.

Comment: Good times! Use the Graph Luke :) Please accept the answer if it was ok for you. The different is to use graph operations (expand) instead of thousands of index lookups.

Answer (score 1):

There *are* index queries in your profile (NodeByQueryIndex).

You can define which index you want to use in your query:

```
MATCH (n:Swedish)
USING INDEX n:Swedish(surname)
WHERE n.surname = 'Taylor'
RETURN n
```

See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-using.html

Comment: We are on legacy indices.  The dba just put in labels, I will retry with the USING clause with the newly labeled nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Our solution was to create labels (lCompany) and add the newer index type on the Company.id column (CREATE INDEX ON :lCompany(id)).

The query was then tweaked to use the new index:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH
     (pfComp:lCompany)<-[c:CHILD_OF*]-(cfComp:lCompany)
WHERE pfComp.id = 2403226
WITH 
    collect(cfComp.id) as cfCompIds
    , pfComp
OPTIONAL MATCH
        (ptComp:lCompany)<-[c2:CHILD_OF*]-(ctComp:lCompany)
WHERE ptComp.id = 1946633
WITH  cfCompIds, 
      collect(ctComp.id)  AS ctCompIds, 
      pfComp, ptComp 
MATCH
      (fComp:lCompany) -[fR:PARTICIPATES_IN]->  cdeals <-[tR:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(tComp:lCompany)
USING INDEX fComp:lCompany(id) //tComp:lCompany(id)
WHERE
                (   
                    fComp.id in (cfCompIds + [2403226])
                ) 
                and
                (
                    tComp.id in (ctCompIds + [1946633])
                )
RETURN  fComp, tComp, cdeals
```

There may be futher optimizations that can be done, but this is as far as we've come so far.

The profiler results are now:

Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 134151 total db hits in 1498 ms.

This is the new profile after the tweak:

[image]